# RequestBody does not map the object correct that has list of objects

Tags: java

Class:

```
    class Person
    {
        private String name;
        private List<Address> addr;
    }
    class Address
    {
        private String street;
        private String city;
    }
```

I was able to directly map the person object using `@RequestBody` attribute however the addr value seem to be null. Is it possible to map this person object directly without instantiating it.

JSON

```
{
    "person" : {
    "name": "Bob",
    "addr": [
        {
        "street": "ABC",
        "city": "XYZ"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the json that you send

Comment: This should not happen. Do you have proper getter and setter method for both classes?

Comment: I don't have setter. i can see the values for name but not for addr.

Comment: What does happen if you try with `private List<Address> addr = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the json a bit.

```
 {
 "name": "Bob",
 "addr": [
    {
    "street": "ABC",
    "city": "XYZ"
    }
    ]
 }
```